# Firefox websocket issue

Tags: javascript, firefox, websocket

I am writing an extension for Firefox using the SDK and within the extension I'm using a websocket to receive messages from a server. the code for the websocket is:

```
if ("WebSocket" in window){
    try{
    var ws = new WebSocket("wss://localhost:8080", "protocolOne");
}
catch(err){
    console.log("error is " + err);
}
```

When I run the extension the code catches this error and the console outputs this line:

```
 [Exception... <"no message"> nsresult: "0x805e0006 <<unknown>>" location:"native
 frame" :: <unknown filename> :: <TOP_LEVEL> :: line 0" data:no]
```

Using Firefox 30, the same extension works fine on chrome.